# How to split a string into columns in bash

Tags: bash

I am making an alias function where it returns some comments which remind me of what alias I need to run for different functionality, this is as example :

```
echo 'sendToDropBox "localFile", "remoteDir"  # send a local file to dropbox ' 
echo 'evernote "title", "conte/file", "notebook_name"  # send to evernote, notebook_name is optional'
```

I want the content starting from `#` to align. I searched columns, but they only seem to work with data coming from a file. I tried this :

```
printf "%s\n" "this is a test" | column -t
```

But that just spaces the words. How can I get this output

```
ToDropBox "localFile", "remoteDir"               # send a local file to dropbox
evernote "title", "conte/file", "notebook_name"  # send to evernote...
tweet "book", "tweet"                            # post a tweet...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` formatting :

```
printf "%-35s %s\n" "line1" "# comment" "line2" "# other comment"
```

`%-35s` reserve 35 characters when displaying first variable (`-` for left align).